# what does instancing do in webgl

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shader, instances

I want to know is any way to understand how many times vertex shader will be called in a draw call in webgl? because I want to know what does instancing realy do, is it call every shared vertices for each instance? so it will call too many time vertex shader

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instancing calls your vertex shader one per vertex per instance. The difference is you can choose 1 or more attributes to only advance once per instance instead of once per vertex.

Normally each attribute advances `stride` bytes for each vertex. `stride` is the second to the last argument of `gl.vertexAttribPointer`. If `stride` is `0` then WebGL compute a stride for you based on `size` and `type` (the 2nd and 3rd arguments to `gl.vertexAttribPointer`.

With instancing you call `gl.vertexAttribDivisor` for certain attributes. 0 is the default normal situation and means 'advance the attribute through the buffer once per vertex. 1 means advance the attribute through the buffer once per instance.

Here's probably the simplest example. Assume you have a quad made from 2 triangles and 6 vertices

```
  -1, -1, 
   1, -1,
  -1,  1,

  -1,  1,
   1, -1,
  -1, -1,
```

You also have a buffer of 3 colors

```
  1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 1,
```

You tell WebGL to read the quad positions like this

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
const size = 2;  // 2 floats per iteration
const type = gl.FLOAT;
const normalize = false;
const stride = 0;  // let WebGL compute the stride based on size and type
const offset = 0;
gl.vertexAttribPointer(posLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
```

For the colors you tell it to use 1 color per instance

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
const size = 3;  // 3 floats per iteration
const type = gl.FLOAT;
const normalize = false;
const stride = 0;  // let WebGL compute the stride based on size and type
const offset = 0;
gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
gl.vertexAttribDivisor(colorLocation, 1);
```

Now when you call `gl.drawArraysInstanced` like this

```
const mode = gl.TRIANGLES;
const first = 0;
const numVerts = 6;  // 6 verts per quad
const numInstances = 3;
gl.drawArraysInstanced(mode, first, numVerts, numInstances);
```

It's going to call your vertex shader 3 * 6 times.  Assuming you had

```
attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec3 color;
```

The values of positions and color for each iteration will be

```
 iteration | position | color  | gl_InstanceID | gl_VertexID
 ----------+----------+--------+---------------+------------
     0     |  -1, -1, | 1,0,0  |      0        |    0
     1     |   1, -1, | 1,0,0  |      0        |    1
     2     |  -1,  1, | 1,0,0  |      0        |    2
     3     |  -1,  1, | 1,0,0  |      0        |    3
     4     |   1, -1, | 1,0,0  |      0        |    4
     5     |  -1, -1, | 1,0,0  |      0        |    5
     6     |  -1, -1, | 0,1,0  |      1        |    0
     7     |   1, -1, | 0,1,0  |      1        |    1
     8     |  -1,  1, | 0,1,0  |      1        |    2
     9     |  -1,  1, | 0,1,0  |      1        |    3
    10     |   1, -1, | 0,1,0  |      1        |    4
    11     |  -1, -1, | 0,1,0  |      1        |    5
    12     |  -1, -1, | 0,0,1  |      2        |    0
    13     |   1, -1, | 0,0,1  |      2        |    1
    14     |  -1,  1, | 0,0,1  |      2        |    2
    15     |  -1,  1, | 0,0,1  |      2        |    3
    16     |   1, -1, | 0,0,1  |      2        |    4
    17     |  -1, -1, | 0,0,1  |      2        |    5
```

Note that `gl_VertexID` and `gl_InstanceID` are only available in WebGL2.

The example above isn't really that useful since it will draw 3 triangles directly on top of one another. It would be more useful to draw the triangles in different places so just like the color attribute, add an `offset` attribute with one offset per instance and add it to the position in the shader. Or better yet, add a `mat4` matrix attribute and set a matrix per instance. Note that `mat4` attributes in the shader take 4 consecutive attribute locations

Comment: excuse me I didn't understood `gl.vertexAttribDivisor` is it just in webgl2?
I read about it `divisor
A GLuint specifying the number of instances that will pass between updates of the generic attribute.` what is happen if it be more than one?

Comment: `gl.vertexAttribDivisor` is part of the [`ANGLE_instanced_arrays` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/ANGLE_instanced_arrays/) in WebGL1.  Specifying a divisor larger than 1 would only proceed to the next data for that attribute once every N instances. For example if you set it to 2 in the table above then color would be read for the first 12 iterations (the first 2 instances) and green for the last 6 iterations (the last instance)

Comment: great explanation. I think it should be `3 floats per iteration` in the comment - not `2`, right?

Comment: correct, fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instancing is supposed to save you a large amount of draw calls (`glDrawArrays` etc) for the same mesh.

However, the vertex shader will still run separately for each vertex and for each instance. It is generally supposed to return different values for each instance.

[The OpenGL wiki explains this clearly](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing):

> The idea is that your vertex shader has some internal mechanism for deciding where each instance of the rendered mesh goes based on a single number. Perhaps it has a table (stored in a Buffer Texture or Uniform Buffer Object) that it indexes with the current vertex's instance number to get the per-instance data it needs. Perhaps it uses an attribute divisor for certain attributes, which provides a different value for each instance. Or perhaps it has a simple algorithm for computing the location of an instance based on its instance number.

Comment: I don't find that remotely clear at all but hey, that's just me